# Bootstrap Modal Footer Button Full Width

Tags: bootstrap-modal

im trying to center and expand the "Close" button to its full width:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogBsV.png

Code so far:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title modalHeading" id="ariaangebote">Title</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn mainBtn btn-block" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Close
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap-5 doesn't have `btn-block` anymore like Bootstrap 4 used to ([Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons)). Its now controlled with grid/flex. In your code, `modal-footer` class is already a flex by default. So all you need do to is add the class `col-12` (or any other value if you want to change the width) to the **button**. It'll become a block button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title modalHeading" id="ariaangebote">Title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```